# Multiple arrays inside a array in javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays

when i do console.log(myArray) I obtain this:

[console.log result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xziS7.png)

I want to take a value inside only one of this arrays, but how? When i do console.log(array[0]) I obtain this result:

```
37.7
28.45
36.38
```

Comment: please explain more clearly what you want to acheive

Comment: I'm also wondering if [`Array.prototype.flat()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flat) might help you.

Comment: Are you saying your input array is: `[[37.7], [28.45], [36.38]]`?

Comment: @vavmxd The screenshot you added only shows the output. Could you please add the code for (or screenshot of) all the related code from setting up or fetching the array, to your `console.log`?

Comment: Oops, i did not realize that my code have a forEach. The console.log was running 3 times. My bad...

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From what I can see in the original question so far, the output of this function is actually three different `console.log()` executions, which leads me to believe that whatever is firing these console.logs is actually running in some sort of loop.

If that is the case, you will not be able to pull just one value out to simply. The screenshot you added only shows the output. Could you please add the code for (or screenshot of) all the related code from setting up or fetching the array, to your `console.log`? With all that context, I can rewrite my answer to get you the exact answer you are looking for.

Comment: I didn't realize that my code have a forEach. The console.log was running 3 times. My bad.

Comment: @vavmxd No worries. Glad you figured it out :)

Answer (score 1):

You have nested arrays. So your main array has three elements each of which contains one number, and the indexes of those arrays go from `0` to `2`.

You access each nested array with its index, and then access the number with the `0` index (because there's only one element in that nested array).

```js
const arr = [[37.7], [28.45], [36.38]];

console.log(arr[0][0]);
console.log(arr[1][0]);
console.log(arr[2][0]);
```

Or even [loop over the array](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Loops_and_iteration) and [destructure the number](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment) from each nested array:

```js
const arr = [[37.7], [28.45], [36.38]];

for (let [number] of arr) {
  console.log(number);
}
```

Comment: when i try this, i got 3 "undefined" messages.

Comment: pls, look at the image that i add to the question, i think it will be more clearly

Answer (score 0):

Please compare your code with this working example:

```
let myArray = [37.7, 28.45, 36.38];
console.log(myArray[0]); // outputs 37.7
```

Comment: when I try console.log(myArray[0]),i got: 37.7;28.45;36.38

Comment: @gndgn please note that recent updates to the question reveal that the input `myArray` actually looks like `[[37.7], [28.45], [36.38]]`.  Perhaps you can revise your answer accordingly?